# PHP files outside Codeigniter's application folder get 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I recently moved a CodeIgniter site to a new server.  Everything is running fine but when attempting to run PHP files on the public folder I get a 404 error message.  This is my current structure:

```
public_html/ 
 |–– application/ 
 |–– public/
 |      |-sample.html
 |      |-simple.php
 |       
 |–– system/ 
 |–– uploads/ 
 |-- .htaccess
 |–– index.php
```

If I go `example.com/public/sample.html` I runs ok.  If I instead try  `example.com/public/simple.php` I get a 404 error.  I checked `.htaccess` but it seems ok and it was actually working ok on the previous server.

Just for illustration purposes this is the current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I already tried a few solutions from SO but none some got me a 500 error, the rest didn't do anything.

Comment: What version of Ci you using?

Comment: Most likely CI 3 (Controllers and Models are capitalized)

Answer (score 1):

On your index.php line 132 if your using codeigniter 3 +

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';
```

Comment: Well, I have views on the standard 'views' directory.  This ´public´ folder is for non-codeigniter related scripts and content.  And, as mentioned before, everything was running smoothly before the server migration.